# React Draft Wysiwyg apply bold, italic or udenderlina to whole content

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs

I need to apply the Bold, Italic, Underline style to the whole content of editor, without selected text, like the align styles but I couldn't find the way for that. Is the possible to change the action or handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You could update your [`SelectionState`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-selection-state) at the moment where your applying style.
Here, we selecting all text

```js
const selection = editorState.getSelection().merge({
  anchorKey: currentContent.getFirstBlock().getKey(),
  anchorOffset: 0,
  focusOffset: currentContent.getLastBlock().getText().length,
  focusKey: currentContent.getLastBlock().getKey()
});
```

Then, we applying new `selection`

```js
const editorStateWithAllSelection = EditorState.acceptSelection(
  editorState,
  selection
);

const newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(
  editorStateWithAllSelection,
  inlineStyle
)
```

if you want to avoid your text to be selected in the end result, we could apply our old selection

```js
const selectionBefore = editorState.getSelection();

// updating selection, toggling style ...

const editorStateWithSelectionBefore = EditorState.acceptSelection(
  newState,
  selectionBefore
);

setEditorState(editorStateWithSelectionBefore);
```

Example on [Codeandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/font-size-inline-d5l2t)

Comment: Really Nice, Thanks.